# add string to the end of a letter python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How can I do the following in python;

```
for i in range(4):
  s_i = 3
```

so I get

```
s_0 = 3
s_1 = 3
s_2 = 3
s_3 = 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the following works, it seems like a very, very bad idea:

```
>>> for j in range(4):
...     globals()['s_{}'.format(j)] = 3
...
>>> s_0
3
>>> s_1
3
>>> s_2
3
>>> s_3
3
```

**EDIT** Replaced `locals()` with `globals()`. According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) for `locals()`:

> The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may
>   not affect the values of local and free variables used by the
>   interpreter.

Comment: It doesn't even work inside a function, which is where most code is.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't... Does work with `globals()`, which makes it an even worse idea...

Answer (score 6):

[Keep data out of your variable names.](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) If you want numbered variables, you really need a list:

```
s = [3] * 4
```

Then you can access elements with indexing notation:

```
s[2] = 5
```

instead of trying to build variable names dynamically.

If you want more general dynamically-named variables, like variables whose names come from user input, you really need a dict:

```
parents = {}
for i in xrange(5):
    child = raw_input('Enter child name:')
    parent = raw_input('Enter parent name:')
    parents[child] = parent
```

Comment: I am trying to do the following
`from astropy.table import Table
for i in range(10):    
    a = range(1000)
    b = range(1000)
    c = range(1000)
    t  = Table([a, b, c], names=('a', 'b', 'c'), meta={'name': 'first table'})`

Comment: so in the loop it keeps updating t which I don't want. I want to save `t` let say `9` times. `t[i]` is not working here.

Comment: @madf19: Make a list. If you don't know how to build and use lists, see the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Comment: I don't think list is the thing I want here. I have to rephrase my question and posted as a new one.

Comment: If you want to read the first n items form the Table 
Use `t[1:9]` or remove the rows which you don't want `t.remove_rows()`
Please go though the [astropy document here](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/table/access_table.html#quick-overview)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your question exactly. But I have tried this:

```
for i in range(4):
    exec('s_'+str(i) + '=i')

Out Put :
    s_0 = 0
    s_1 = 1
    s_2 = 2
    s_3 = 3
```

on the fly we are creating 4 variables and assigning values to it.

Comment: If you find yourself using either `exec` or `eval`, that usually means it's time to re-think what you're doing. [They can both be very dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), and there's almost always a safer, better alternative.